# Python Subplot with Linked Axis similar to MATLAB Linkaxes

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, subplot

I'm using matplotlib to generate a subplot of two dataframes. What is the Python equivalent of MATLAB's Linkaxes function to allow for axis linked zooming? It doesn't seem to be the Pyplot property of sharex=True because sharex is only partially similar to MATLAB Linkaxe in that does link the axes as you zoom, BUT the biggest difference is the fact that if sharex=True is invoked, the two plots will be offset due to them being of different X scale to begin with.

ie. ax1 goes from 0:40000, but ax2 is from 0:20000. When plotted together with sharex=True, the two graphs are offset by 20000 before its even linked.

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, len(df_1['Data'])/20, len(df_1['Data']))
x2 = np.linspace(0, len(df_2['Data']), len(df_2['Data']))

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
df_1['Data'].plot(x=x1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(2,1,2, sharex=True) # Causes 20000 offset on X axis
df_2['Data'].plot(x=x2)
```

Comment: If the scaling is not identical to begin with, how should zooming be synchronized? I.e. if you have an axes with range [0,1] and another with range [10,100], and you zoom the first to the range [0,.5], what is the expected outcome for the second axis?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I should've added in the code for the X axes as well in the example above. The raw datasets are of different sizes, but when plotted, their X axes are scaled using linspace. The code above is pretty much identical to my MATLAB script, except in MATLAB it works perfectly using "Linkaxes", but in Python it doesn't work using "sharex" probably because I don't want them to "share" axes, but I want them to have their own axis but linked during zooming.

Comment: Mind that I have no idea what "Linkaxes" does. That is why I asked the question in the above comment. If it is clear what you are expecting for that case, one can find a solution to replicate that with matplotlib.

Comment: It seems matplotlib just isn't able to plot with multiple X axes in subplots and align them visually together on a graph. I solved it by plotting over two equal date_ranges() instead